# Showing a mean-curvature related function decreases on the level sets of a function with non zero gradient

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have an $n$-dimensional complete, non compact Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ that satisfies $Ric_g \ge 0$, a bounded open domain $\Omega \subset M$ and a smooth function $u$ defined on $M$ such that, having called $\Sigma$ the boundary of $\Omega$, it holds that

1. $|\nabla u| = H > 0$ on $M \setminus \Omega$
2. $ u = 0 $ on $\Sigma$
3. $ u(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as the distance between $x$ and $\Sigma$ goes to $\infty$

where $H$ is the mean curvature on the hypersurfaces $\Sigma_t = \{u = t\}$ computed wrt the normal vector given by the $(1,0)$ version of the 1-form $\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}$ (this is orthogonal to $\Sigma_t$ thanks to the generalized Gauss' lemma).
I would like to prove that the function
$$
\int_{\Sigma_t} (\frac{H}{n-1})^{n-1}d\sigma
$$
is nonincreasing for positive values of $t$.

I have already proved that, having called $g_{ij}$ the coefficients of the metric on $\Sigma_t$ given by the coordinates of the Gauss'lemma (i.e. wherever $\nabla u \not = 0 $ the metric on $M$ will be written as $\frac{du \otimes du}{|\nabla u|^2} + g_{ij}d\theta_i \otimes d\theta_j$) the equalities
$$
h_{ij} = \frac{|\nabla u|}{2} \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial u} 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = -\Delta^{\Sigma_t}(\frac{1}{|\nabla u|})-\frac{|h|^2}{|\nabla u|} -|\nabla u|Ric_{uu} 
$$
both hold and I was hoping to exploit them in some way.

However, I am not able to show that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} < 0$, and even worse when I try to calculate the derivative for $\Sigma_t$'s area, using the fact that $|\nabla u| = H$ and hypothesis $1$ I get
$$
|\nabla u| = H = g^{ij}h_{ij} = g^{ij}\frac{|\nabla u|}{2} \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial u}
$$
and therefore $g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial u} = 2$. Using this with some easy calculations yields that
$$
\frac{\partial \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}}{\partial t} = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}
$$
which is obviously positive, while I would really like $\Sigma_t$'s area to be decreasing. Is there any more sensible approach to proving this?